# Which property should I use for my product video?

Tags: video, schema, e-commerce, product

On an e-commerce site I have schema tags for my product info. I added some videos to popular products. Now I want to associate these videos with my schema in product pages.

Which property should I use?

I think https://schema.org/VideoObject is not related with product.

Does [review](https://schema.org/Review) property meet my request?

Answer (score 0):

The product video isn't a `Review` so I don't think that is right. I would use `VideoObject`.

There are enough Properties in `VideoObject` to make meaningful references to the associated product.